# Preventing "onSuccess" firing when there is no connection to an adapter?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, ibm-mobilefirst

Using MobileFirst v6.3, whenever I communicate with an adapter using WL.Client.invokeProcedure, the onSuccess function ALWAYS fires, regardless of actual success or not. This includes when the mobile device is completely offline.

onConnectionFailure still functions as expected, firing after the adapter times out, but having onSuccess fire is essentially useless.

Sample code:

```
var invocationData = {
                    adapter : 'MaximoLogin',
                    procedure : 'setValue',
                    parameters : [itemid,value]
                };

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
                onSuccess : valueSuccess(itemid),
                onConnectionFailure: connectivityFailure,
                onFailure : connectFailure
            });
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your code as follows:

```
var invocationData = {
  adapter : 'MaximoLogin',
  procedure : 'setValue',
  parameters : [itemid,value]
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
  onSuccess : valueSuccess,
  onConnectionFailure: connectivityFailure,
  onFailure : connectFailure,
  invocationContext : {
    itemid: itemid
  }
});

// your success function
function valueSuccess(response) {
  // get the item id from the invocationContext object
  var successItemId = response.invocationContext.itemid;

  // handle your success ...
}
```

The reason why your `valueSuccess` function is always called is because you are always calling it i.e.: `valueSuccess(itemid)`. `onSuccess` takes a callback function and you are invoking the function that's why it always runs.

If you want to pass some variable to your callback functions you use `invocationContext` which is an object that will be passed to your callback functions both `onSuccess` and `onFailure`.

Comment: And another resource to read through is this blog post on Handling Backend Responses in Adapters: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/handling_backend_responses_in_adapters?lang=en